# Getting two jquery elements (jcarousel and accordion) to work on the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcarousel, jquery-ui-accordion

I have a page I am creating that needs to have a jcarousel and an accordion implemented in jquery.

here is the page.
http://www.ikeepsafe.org/template/

I can get each on to work individually but I can't get them both to work at the same time. Some help would be appreciated.

I did try to have the commands be in the same script element but that didn't work either.

Cheers,
James

This is the javascript I used for the carousel.

```
<script src="http://baijs.nl/tinycarousel/js/jquery.tinycarousel.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">         
$(document).ready(function(){               

    $('#slider-code').tinycarousel({ pager: true });

});
</script>
```

For the Accordion

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
        collapsible: true,
        heightStyle: "content",
    });
}); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be `jquery conflict` issue . Use `jQuery.noConflict()` method or try wrapping the code like this:

```
 (function($){
 ....
 })(jQuery);
```

Check here for more info:http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#slider1').tinycarousel({
        pager: true
    });

    $("#accordion").accordion({
        collapsible: true,
        heightStyle: "content",
    });   
    });
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/auv3y/